How to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x) \ln^2(x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1 - x} \, dx$

Question

How to evaluate
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x) \ln^2(x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1 - x} \, dx$$

My attempt

A common substitution for integrals involving logarithms is to set $x = 1 - u$,
$x = 1 - u \quad \text{so} \quad dx = -du$
With this substitution, the limits of integration change as follow
When $x = 0$, $u = 1$.
When $x = 1$, $u = 0$.
Substitute into the integral:
$$I = \int_1^0 \frac{\ln^2(1-(1-u)) \ln^2(1-u) \ln^2(1+(1-u))}{u} (-du)$$
Simplifying the logarithmic terms:
$\ln(1 - (1 - u)) = \ln(u)$
$\ln(1 + (1 - u)) = \ln(2 - u)$
Thus, the integral becomes:
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(u) \ln^2(1-u) \ln^2(2-u)}{u} \, du$$
We now need to evaluate:
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(u) \ln^2(1-u) \ln^2(2-u)}{u} \, du$$
Another substitutions
$u = e^{-t} \quad \Rightarrow \quad du = -e^{-t} \, dt$
Thus, the integral becomes:
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(e^{-t}) \ln^2(1 - e^{-t}) \ln^2(2 - e^{-t})}{e^{-t}} (-e^{-t}) \, dt$$
Simplify the logarithmic terms:
$\ln(e^{-t}) = -t$
Thus, the integral becomes:
$$I = \int_0^\infty t^2 \ln^2(1 - e^{-t}) \ln^2(2 - e^{-t}) \, dt$$
At this point, I am completely stuck. For context, this question is a modified version of similar types of integrals found on the site.

Sanity check: By $\ln^2(x)$, you mean $(\ln(x))^2$, not $\ln(\ln(x))$, right?

@Dan WHY? $ \ln^2(x) $ means $ (\ln(x))^2 $.

For me, it's useless all these changes of variable.
A way (not sure it will work) to do:
Consider the integrals \begin{align}J_{r,s,t}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^r(1-x)\ln^sx\ln^t(1+x)}{1+x}dx\\end{align} with $r+s+t=6$

Try to express your integral as a sum of $J_{r,s,t}$
Try to find enough relations (rational linear combinations) betweeen $J_{r,s,t}$
Some of $J_{r,s,t}$ are "easily" computable as $J_{0,0,6}$ or $J_{6,0,0}$.

NB:
In fact, it's more difficult because you will get integrals,
\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2\ln^r(1-x)\ln^sx\ln^t(1+x)}{1+x}dx\end{align}with $r+s+t=5$

You will have to consider integrals
\begin{align}K_{r,s,t}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^r(1-x)\ln^sx\ln^t(1+x)}{1+x}dx\end{align}with $r+s+t=5$ and so on.
NB2:
Why to consider integrals $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{...}{1+x}dx$?
Because $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{1+x}$ is invariant by the change of variable $\displaystyle u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

@Dan: $\ln^2x$ means $(\ln x)^2$ today,. Maybe, $\ln^{(2)}x$ means $\ln(\ln x)$.

Mathematica with Package MultipleZetaValues  can compute and give  long answer.It's so long that I can't post it here in a comment.

@MariuszIwaniuk Post it in two parts. I can't check the closed form since I don't use Mathematica. Or, can you share the notebook link?

FWIW, WolframAlpha gives a numerical result of $0.0970087$.

Where did you find this integral? Your attempt reminded me of this beautiful idea presented here, maybe this can help to continue with your original attempt

Is not really the Answer ,only solution given from Mathematica with package MultipleZetaValues:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(1-x) \log ^2(x) \log ^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx=-\frac{1915 \pi ^6 \log (2)}{36288}-\frac{283 \pi ^4 \log ^3(2)}{16560}-\frac{149 \pi ^2 \log
   ^5(2)}{3105}+\frac{1283 \log ^7(2)}{21735}+16 \text{MultiZeta}(\{5,1,1\},\{-1,1,1\})-10 \text{MultiZeta}(\{5,1,1\},\{1,-1,1\})+\frac{8}{3} \log ^3(2)
   \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2 \pi ^2 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+8 \log ^2(2) \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1024}{69} \log (2)
   \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+32 \text{Li}_7\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1024}{69} \log (2)
   \Re\left(\text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{2279 \pi ^4 \zeta (3)}{2880}-\frac{29}{6} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2) \zeta (3)+\frac{23}{12} \log ^4(2)
   \zeta (3)+4 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \zeta (3)+\frac{371}{8} \log (2) \zeta (3)^2-\frac{3211 \pi ^2 \zeta (5)}{192}+\frac{899}{16} \log ^2(2) \zeta
   (5)+\frac{837 \zeta (7)}{4}\approx 0.0970087$$ where  $\text{MultiZeta}$ is:


I would say that the original integral is a wonderful closed form for the mega expression on the right side of the equals sign.

This is not a full answer to the problem. It is just some potentially useful tools. In the bank of definite integrals, there are some logarithmic things divided by $1-x$ integrated from $0$ to $1$. I'll give them to you in the hopes that someone smarter than I can work out how to combine them to make your question.
$$I_{1}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)\ln^{2}(1-x)\ln(2-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(5)$$
$$I_{2}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln^{2}(2-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{2}{15}\ln^{5}(2)-\frac{2}{3}\ln^{3}(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{7}{4}\ln^{2}(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{8}\zeta(5)+4\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+4\operatorname{Li}_{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$I_{3}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}(2-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)$$
$$I_{4}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)\ln(2-x)}{1-x}dx=-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)$$
$$I_{5}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)}{1-x}dx=2\zeta(3)$$
$$I_{6}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(\ln(1-x)-\ln(2)\right)^{2}\left(\ln(1+x)-\ln(2)\right)^{2}}{1-x}dx=\frac{1}{8}\zeta(5)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{2}{3}\ln^{3}(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{7}{4}\ln^{2}(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{15}\ln^{5}(2)+4\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+4\operatorname{Li}_{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
So there's no doubt, $I_{2}$ is similar to $I_{6}$ but they are distinct.
Edit: I just noticed the author asked a similar question, which had a closed form provided. It could be very useful indeed for this one. I'll attach it here in case someone would have missed it.
$$I_{7}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x}dx=-\frac{4}{3} \pi ^2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{131 \zeta^{2}(3)}{16}+\frac{7}{3} \zeta (3) \ln ^3(2)-\frac{77}{24} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \ln (2)+\frac{217}{8} \zeta (5) \ln (2)+\frac{41 \pi ^6}{30240}-\frac{1}{18} \pi    ^2 \ln^4(2)-\frac{1}{144} \pi ^4 \ln^2(2)$$
Edit 2: if I'm understanding this "weight" idea correctly, this should be a weight 7 integral, which might be more useful, I think. I'm not really sure.
$$I_{8}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)\ln^{4}(1-x)\ln(2-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{9}{4}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)+\frac{45}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{363}{16}\zeta(7)$$

Your integrals cannot help to solve the question asked. The asked integral is of weight 7, your integrals are of weight 5. By the way, i think i can compute your $I_1$.

Just to check what you mean by weight - would it be weight 7 if there were 7 logarithms multiplied together, or 6 logarithms and one reciprocal of a linear multiplied together? If so, I have a weight 7 and weight 9 which are similar to $I_{1}$ that I could add (though the powers aren't exactly distributed evenly, which is why I initially left them).

The asked integral have a numerator as being a product of six logarithms, the weight is 7, here. This concept of weight isn't well defined, but if you observe your  $I_7$ integral for example, the numerator is the product of 5 logarithms and it's equal to a sum of terms of weight 6. How to count? log(2) and $\pi$ count $1$, $\zeta(n)$ and $\displaystyle \text{Li}_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$count $n$ and the weight of the product of numbers of weight $p$ and $q$ is $p+q$. Moreover, Catalan constant counts $2$ and of course, rational numbers count $0$.

More often this type of integrals have a closed-form as being a sum of numbers having the weight of the integral. Here, the asked integral have a weight of $7$ so it's unlikely you'll find terms of weight $<7$

Is this the sort of thing you mean? I'm still a bit confused by it. My fault, not yours.

Look at the closed-form given, you'll observe that all terms of the sum have weight 7. In particular, MultiZeta, $5+1+1=7$.

Several numbers of different weight don't nullify a rational linear combination (it's a conjectural statement)

Not really an answer,
$$ I\underset{x\to t}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-t) \ln^2(t) \ln^2(1+t)}{1 - t} \, dt$$

$$x^2y^2=\frac{(x+y)^4+(x-y)^4-2x^4-2y^4}{12}$$
$$x=\ln(1-t)\,||||\,y=\ln(1+t)$$
$$(\ln(1-t))^2(\ln(1+t))^2=\frac{(\ln(1-t)+\ln(1+t))^4+(\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^4-2(\ln(1-t))^4-2(\ln(1+t))^4}{12}$$
$$\ln^2(1-t)\ln^2(1+t)=\frac{(\ln(1-t)+\ln(1+t))^4+(\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^4-2\ln^4(1-t)-2\ln^4(1+t)}{12}$$
$$\ln^2(1-t)\ln^2(1+t)=\frac{(\ln(1-t)+\ln(1+t))^4}{12}+\frac{(\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^4}{12}-\frac{\ln^4(1-t)}{6}-\frac{\ln^4(1+t)}{6}$$
The above integral becomes,
$$I=\int_{0}^1 \frac{(\ln(1-t)+\ln(1+t))^4\ln^2(t)}{12(1-t)}+\frac{(\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^4\ln^2(t)}{12(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^4(1-t)\ln^2(t)}{6(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^4(1+t)\ln^2(t)}{6(1-t)}\,dt$$
$$I=\frac{1}{12}I_1+\frac{1}{12}I_2-\frac{1}{6}I_3-\frac{1}{6}I_4\tag1$$
Where,
$$I_1=\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln^4(1-t^2)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt\tag2$$
$$I_2=\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt\tag3$$
$$I_3=\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln^4(1-t)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt\tag4$$
$$I_4=\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+t)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt\tag5$$
Solving these heavy four integrals is hard

Now using the Beta function to evaluate $(4)$,
$$\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\,dt=\beta(a,b)$$
$$\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\ln^2(t)\ln^4(1-t)\,dt=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial b^4} \left(\beta(a,b)\right)$$
$$\boxed{I_3=\lim_{(a,b)\to (1,0)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial b^4} \left(\beta(a,b)\right)}$$
An alternate method would be as follows,
We have,
$$\frac{\ln^4(1-t)}{1-t}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^n(H_n^4-6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3(H^{(2)}_n)^2-6H_n^{(4)})$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-t)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^n\ln^2(t)(H_n^4-6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3(H^{(2)}_n)^2-6H_n^{(4)})\,dt$$
$$\boxed{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-t)\ln^2(t)}{1-t}\,dt=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^4-6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3(H^{(2)}_n)^2-6H_n^{(4)}}{n^{3} + 3n^{2} + 3n + 1}}$$

FWIW regarding $I_2$,
Substituting $\frac{1-t}{1+t}=x$,
$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t(1+t)} \, dt$$
Using the identity,
$$\displaystyle \ln ^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)=-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}t^{2n}$$
$$\boxed{I_2=-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2n}\ln^4(t)}{t(1+t)}\,dt}$$

Or exploring this path,
$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) (\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^2}{t(1+t)} \,
 dt$$
$$(\ln(1-t)-\ln(1+t))^2=\ln^2(1-t)+\ln^2(1+t)-2\ln(1-t)\ln(1+t)$$
$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln^2(1-t)}{t(1+t)} \,
 dt+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln^2(1+t)}{t(1+t)} \, dt-2\int_{0}^{1}
 \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln(1-t)\ln(1+t)}{t(1+t)} \, dt$$

$$I_2=J+K-2L$$
We can try the following two formulas for $L=\int_{0}^{1}
 \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln(1-t)\ln(1+t)}{t(1+t)} \, dt$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1} H_n x^n=\frac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x)}$$
$$\int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-\frac{H_n}{n}$$
For the integral $K=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln^2(1+t)}{t(1+t)} \, dt$, we can try
$$\ln^2(1+x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{n-1}x^n$$
For $J=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^4(t) \ln^2(1-t)}{t(1+t)} \,
 dt$, nothing seems doable currently

Maybe a similar line is followed to evaluate $I_1$ and $I_4$ but looking at @Mariusz Iwaniuk's provided close form, it's not going to involve a sane amount of calculation
